# How to test custom Repository in Nestjs/TypeORM applications

Tags: nestjs, typeorm

I am trying to add more testing codes to improve the quality of my sample codes.

Currently, I have a problem when testing `UserRepository` (**not mock UserRepository**),  there are some custom methods I added in my custom `UserRepository` like this.

```js
@EntityRepository(UserEntity)
export class UserRepository extends Repository<UserEntity> {
  findByEmail(email: string): Promise<UserEntity> {
    return this.findOne({ email: email });
  }
}
```

So I want to verify the `findOne` is called from the parent `Repository`.

I tried to add the following testing codes.

```js
describe('UserRepository', () => {
  let local;
  let parentMock;

  beforeEach(() => {
    local = Object.getPrototypeOf(UserRepository);
    parentMock = {
      new: jest.fn(),
      construtor: jest.fn(),
      findOne: jest.fn(),
    };
    Object.setPrototypeOf(UserRepository, parentMock);
  });

  afterEach(() => {
    Object.setPrototypeOf(UserRepository, local);
  });

  it('should call findOne', async () => {
    const findByEmailSpy = jest.spyOn(parentMock, 'findOne');
    const users = new UserRepository();
    await users.findByEmail('test@example.com');
    expect(parentMock.mock.calls.length).toBe(1);
    expect(findByEmailSpy).toBeCalledWith({
      email: 'test@example.com',
    });
  });
});
```

When running the tests, it complains there is no constructor() for `new UserRepository()`.

Is there any way to fix this issue, or a better way to write these testing codes?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In order to properly test the user repository, `findOne` method has to be mocked.

```js
import { Test, TestingModule } from '@nestjs/testing';
import { Repository } from 'typeorm';
import { UserEntity } from './user.entity';
import { UserRepository } from './user.repository';

describe('UserRepository', () => {
  let userRepository: UserRepository;

  beforeEach(async () => {
    const module: TestingModule = await Test.createTestingModule({
      providers: [UserRepository],
    }).compile();

    userRepository = module.get<UserRepository>(UserRepository);
  });

  describe('findByEmail', () => {
    it('should return found user', async () => {
      const email = 'email';
      const user = {
        email,
      };
      const findOneSpy = jest
        .spyOn(userRepository, 'findOne')
        .mockResolvedValue(user as UserEntity);

      const foundUser = await userRepository.findByEmail(email);
      expect(foundUser).toEqual(user);
      expect(findOneSpy).toHaveBeenCalledWith(user);
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: If use EntityManager and QueryBuilder in the  `Repository`, eg [`findByAuthor` in the PostRepository](https://github.com/hantsy/nestjs-graphql-sample/blob/master/api/src/database/repository/post.repository.ts#L16),  how to mock this?

Comment: for QueryBuilder, it can be mocked like the following:
`jest.spyOn(Repository.prototype, 'createQueryBuilder').mockReturnValue(SelectQueryBuilder.prototype);
 jest.spyOn(SelectQueryBuilder.prototype, 'where').mockReturnThis();
 // the same goes for setParameter, skip and take methods
 jest.spyOn(SelectQueryBuilder.prototype, 'getMany').mockResolvedValue(data);
`

Comment: not sure about mocking `manager.findOne`, what is the reason for using `this.manager.find` instead of `this.find`?

Comment: I added [a test](https://github.com/hantsy/nestjs-graphql-sample/blob/master/api/src/database/repository/post.repository.spec.ts#L22-L43) make it work. But all *readonly* properties in the `Repository` should be injectable, but it does not work as expected like other injectable components.

Comment: Any ideas on how to do this when extending from `AbstractRepository`? I have created a separate [question for it here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70521273/how-to-unit-test-a-custom-repository-of-typeorm-in-nestjs).