# How to unit test a custom repository of TypeORM in NestJS?

Tags: typescript, unit-testing, jestjs, nestjs, typeorm

### Class to test

My TypeORM repository `extends` [AbstractRepository](https://orkhan.gitbook.io/typeorm/docs/custom-repository#custom-repository-extends-standard-abstractrepository):

```
@EntityRepository(User)
export class UsersRepository extends AbstractRepository<User> {

  async findByEmail(email: string): Promise<User> {
    return await this.repository.findOne({ email })
  }
}
```

---

### Unit test

```
describe('UsersRepository', () => {
  let usersRepository: UsersRepository

  beforeEach(async () => {
    const module: TestingModule = await Test.createTestingModule({
      providers: [UsersRepository]
    }).compile()

    usersRepository = module.get<UsersRepository>(UsersRepository)
  })

  describe('findByEmail', () => {
    it(`should return the user when the user exists in database.`, async () => {
      const fetchedUser = await usersRepository.findByEmail('test1@test.com')
    })
  })
})
```

Here, I get the error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'getRepository' of undefined

      at UsersRepository.get (repository/AbstractRepository.ts:43:29)
      at UsersRepository.findByEmail (users/users.repository.ts:11:23)
      at Object.<anonymous> (users/users.repository.spec.ts:55:49)
```

So, my question is, how do I mock the `repository` or `repository.findOne`?

In other words, how do I mock the fields that are inherited from the `AbstractRepository` which are `protected` and cannot be accessed from `UsersRepository` instance?

There is a [similar question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67580233/how-to-test-custom-repository-in-nestjs-typeorm-applications) but it is for extending from `Repository<Entity>` instead of `AbstractRepository<Entity>`. They are able to mock `findOne` because it's `public`.

---

### What I tried

I tried to mock it in a NestJS recommended way, but this is for non-custom repositories and doesn't work in my case:

```
{
  provide: getRepositoryToken(User),
  useValue: {
    findOne: jest.fn().mockResolvedValue(new User())
  }
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I went with the in-memory database solution. This way I don't have to mock the complex queries of TypeORM. The unit tests run as fast without hitting the real database.

My production database is PostgreSQL, but I'm able to use SQLite in-memory database for unit testing. This works because the TypeORM provides an abtraction over databases. It doesn't matter what database we are using under the hood as long as we are satisfying the interface of our repository.

Here's how my tests look like:

```
const testConnection = 'testConnection'

describe('UsersRepository', () => {
  let usersRepository: UsersRepository

  beforeEach(async () => {
    const connection = await createConnection({
      type: 'sqlite',
      database: ':memory:',
      dropSchema: true,
      entities: [User],
      synchronize: true,
      logging: false,
      name: testConnection
    })

    usersRepository = connection.getCustomRepository(UsersRepository)
  })

  afterEach(async () => {
    await getConnection(testConnection).close()
  })

  describe('findByEmail', () => {
    it(`should return the user when the user exists in database.`, async () => {
      await usersRepository.createAndSave(testUser)
      const fetchedUser = await usersRepository.findByEmail(testUser.email)
      expect(fetchedUser.email).toEqual(testUser.email)
    })
  })
})
```

Comment: Does it fit to the column type you declare for the entity? i am asking since i am using also postgres and one of the column is json type, also i have enum's

Comment: @MatanTubul, if you are using the TypeORM over the postgres, it should work although I haven't tested it. TypeORM queries eventually get converted to postgres or SQLite queries behind the scenes, depending on the database.